# Can I trade a resource for a development card?

Tags: catan

Is it legal to trade resources for development cards another player is holding in hand?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No it is not. Development cards cannot be traded at all.

From [the rules](http://www.catan.com/en/download/?SoC_rv_Rules_091907.pdf), page 7:

> You cannot trade or give away Development Cards.